# Verify if an Outlook Email Sent From VB.net was Actually Sent

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook

I'm writing some code in VB.net which will zip some files with a password & email them to the recipient(s) & then send a second email to the recipient(s) with the password for the zip file. The email is sent through Outlook.

The people who would be using this also have some VBA code in the Application_ItemSend event procedure in Outlook which checks if there's attachments being sent to external email addresses & if so it gives the user the details & the option to Cancel sending the email - this is done using the Cancel property/argument (sorry I'm not good with the correct terminology for things in VBA/VB.net) of the Application_ItemSend event procedure.

If the user does cancel the first email then I'd like to stop the second email from going out aswell. I've tried checking (directly after invoking `MailItem.Send()`) `MailItem.Sent.ToString` but it bugs out on that line & gives this exception - `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The item has been moved or deleted.`

My first thought was that once `MailItem.Send()` was invoked that `MailItem` became nothing, but I've just put a watch for `MailItem Is Nothing` & it's returning `False`. I've tried searching but not been able to find anything.

I can work around by displaying the second email & leave it to the user to send or cancel but if possible I'd rather have the code take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending the second email immediately, wait until `Items.ItemAdd` event fires on the Sent Items folder. Once the first message raises that event, you can create and send the second email.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dmitry but I don't think I can check if an event has triggered from vb.net code. Even if you could some stuff could be missed e.g. if a user didn't bother or notice to click the OK button on the pop up they get then this approach could incorrectly take it as cancelled. I know I could add in some sort of timer but that wouldn't be the perfect solution as it'd mean the application would be held up for whatever time period I set the time for when they choose to Cancel the email & if for some reason they click OK but not within the period it would be treated as a Cancel.